# Sylius how to override the CoreBundle Checkout process

Tags: symfony, overriding, checkout, sylius

I'm working on a project and I'd like to ask for a clean/best way to override the steps in the

Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Checkout\CheckoutProcessScenario

I'd like to preserve the custom mechanics of the whole process just add a custom step at the end and remove the finalize step.

```
    $builder
        ->add('security', 'sylius_checkout_security')
        ->add('addressing', 'sylius_checkout_addressing')
        ->add('shipping', 'sylius_checkout_shipping')
        ->add('finalize', 'sylius_checkout_finalize')
        ->add('payment', 'sylius_checkout_payment')
        ->add('purchase', 'sylius_checkout_purchase')
    ;
```

What's the best form of doing so? If it's extending the bundle and overwriting it I'd like some help with that of at least some information to point me in the right direction - currently I'm not getting any results on my own.

I've read the docs on the bundle itself but it doesn't explain how to override the built in process.

I've also read the symfony cookbook on extending resources:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-translations-validation-etc

and:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

If anyone has some experience on the topic and would like to share thier insights I'd be very gratefull. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it a bit different but still the point was good :)

What I've done is use the service compiler to override it with my own class and override the original file. The basics are explained here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

in the Services & Configuration section :)

Then I just had to include the compiler pass

```
// src/Acme/ShopBundle/AcmeShopBundle.php
namespace Acme\ShopBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\ShopBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CustomCompilerPass;

class AcmeMailerBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Inside the compiler pass I just extended the base file and overwrote the function I needed. Droppin it by in case anyone needs to pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the service class to a custom one. 
You can overwrite the parameter `sylius.checkout_scenario.class`.

***app/config/config.yml:***

```
<parameter key="sylius.checkout_scenario.class">
    Your\Class
</parameter>
```